# AngularJS при передаче даты на сервер минусуется день

Tags: angularjs, дата, timezone

Использую стандартный компонент для ввода/вывода даты `<input type="date"  ng-model-options="{timezone:'UTC'}" ng-model="vm.employe.dob>` при передаче данных на сервер отправляет корректную дату, потому как установил timezone, но при приёме данных (даты) с сервера, дата отображается на один день меньше (приходят данные 16.07.2019 (в функции), отображаются 15.07.2019), если установить timezone: timezoneOffset, тогда данные с сервера отображаются норм, но сохраняются на сервер снова на день меньше. замкнутый круг.
Как решить такую проблему?

Comment: Какой сервер используете? Можно пример кода клиентской и серверной части? В каком формате передаёте дату?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у Вас с сервера приходит дата в одной перспективе, а клиент автоматически конвертирует ее в другую.

Например, сервер отправляет дату с локальной перспективой, скажем `2019-09-06T00:00:00`. Поскольку в этом примере нет на конце буквы Z, которая обозначает UTC, то клиент может воспринять ее как локальную. Допустим сервер у Вас настроен на Московское время, значит смещение UTC+3. Когда клиент конвертирует дату из локальной в UTC, то отнимает 3 часа. Получаем `2019-09-05T21:00:00Z`.

Вообще сценарии могут быть разные, нужно видеть данные, которые Вы передаёте и получаете с сервера.

Comment: с сервера приходят данные в виде набора строк `<input type="date" ng-model-options="{timezone:'UTC'}" ng-disabled="render.checkRenderRigth('EditEmploye', true)"
                                                   ng-model="vm.employe.dob"/>`, написал функцию. которая парсит дату и возвращает её в формате UTC

Comment: ` function convertToUtcDate(date) {
            if (date) {
                var tempdata = new Date(date);
                var year = tempdata.getFullYear();
                var month = tempdata.getMonth();
                var day = tempdata.getDate();
                return new Date(Date.UTC(year,month,day));
            } else
                return null;

        };`

Comment: теперь всё отображается корректно, как при получении, так и при отправке. Вот только вопрос, правильно ли реализовал такую конвертацию?